# copy from 1 query result to another one on some specific property

Tags: c#, linq, windows-phone

I have this function:

```
public void copy(string abc)
{
var query_1 = from Book s in BookDB.Books where (s.Author == abc && s.AuthorCV != "") select s;
var query_2 = from Book x in BookDB.Books where (x.Author == abc && x.AuthorCV == "") select x;
}
```

My problem is how can I copy AuthorCV from query_1 to AuthorCV in query_2...please help me

Comment: I would not do that. I'd make `AuthorCV` a property of `Author`, that's where it belongs. The need to copy data usually indicates design flaws in a relational environment.

Answer (score -1):

Try casting both queries to `Book` and then copy from one an other and then persist the second:

```
Book book1 = (Book)query_1;
Book book2 = (Book)query_2;
book2.AuthorCV=book1.AuthorCV;
```

And then persist `book2` to save the changes.

Comment: Impossible, query_1 (and 2) is `IQueryable<Book>`.